# Pandas: search and add values to cells of multiple column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I search a dataframe like this `df[df['a'] > 5]` and then I want to add 5 and 10 respectively to column `b` and `c` of the search result.

For example,

```
 a  b  c
 7  2  5
 3  4  7
 6  1  3
```

now I want to add 5 and 10 to cells where a>5 and the result should look like this

```
 a  b  c
 7  7  15
 3  4  7
 6  6  13
```

So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One-liner that will do the trick:

```
df.loc[df.a > 5, ['b', 'c']] += (5, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In[223]:
(df['b'],df['c']) = np.where(df['a'] > 5, (df['b'] + 5, df['c'] + 10), (df['b'],df['c']))
df

Out[223]: 
   a  b   c
0  7  7  15
1  3  4   7
2  6  6  13
```

Here we pass the boolean condition as the first arg `df['a'] > 5`, when `True` it returns a tuple of the cols of interest with the scalar value added, when `False` it returns the original df, the trick here is to construct a tuple of the different operations so we can perform 2 distinct operations and assign these to a tuple of the same cols

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use loc like this:

```
df.loc[df['a']>5,'b'] +=5
df.loc[df['a']>5,'c'] += 10
```