# Python: CSV file with multiple headers - combine into one data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, data-cleaning

I want to use some data from the NOAA website. It is a csv file with data for all hurricanes since 1851, with a format like this: [Format example / README file](https://storage.googleapis.com/kaggle-datasets/692/1307/atlantic.pdf?GoogleAccessId=web-data@kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1528119944&Signature=N5nu8BId0S5GBN0btBrvAYXzuBrOdgCuJrwcfNGXcLVgzDvjFV3BCNNAW2Qj1Fhkl2m%2FTkkgJMwchR3DK5V39fKZANhAoe64BGpKcwGJuBLZ3UulZ6syq43vqAWNf29siHy3ghzsE%2FOdoZssHIwK%2B0MY1lMs1R41p%2FZzVdjZ7%2Bg4n0EtVir4is0zwRfQLi0Z1wT0dgJrNrLFzmjtTpZhuDN75x4Tl5u%2FEeA3o9Rx31GH8ts3emEIK2jXPNf567wvXt6%2FOAMJWJSigOrYYQ4CrIbbEy%2FUPkR3rIgc4oGG%2FFSFUvHL2TEkB5Y%2F6Ub4FWIu%2BzMjO%2FrhLx2GO7TjCZq%2Fng%3D%3D)

As you can see, although everything is contained within one csv file, each hurricane has it's own table, with a separate header.

How can I remove the headers and put the information in a "Hurricane Name" column instead? I want to combine everything into a single data frame, so it's easier to use. Thanks!

Example:

> AL092011,              IRENE,     3,
>
> 20110821, 0000,  , TS, 15.0N,  59.0W,  45, 1006,  105,    0,    0,
>   45,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
>
> 20110821, 0600,  , TS, 16.0N,  60.6W,  45, 1006,  130,    0,    0,
>   80,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
>
> 20110821, 1200,  , TS, 16.8N,  62.2W,  45, 1005,  130,    0,    0,
>   70,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
>
> AL092012,              ANOTHER_NAME,     2,
>
> 20110821, 1800,  , TS, 17.5N,  63.7W,  50,  999,  130,   20,    0,
>   70,   30,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
>
> 20110822, 0000,  , TS, 17.9N,  65.0W,  60,  993,  130,   30,   30,
>   90,   30,    0,    0,   30,    0,    0,    0,    0,

I would like the header information into columns, like so:

> AL092011, IRENE, 20110821, 0000,  , TS, 15.0N,  59.0W,  45, 1006,  105,    0,    0,
>   45,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
>
> AL092011, IRENE, 20110821, 0600,  , TS, 16.0N,  60.6W,  45, 1006,  130,    0,    0,
>   80,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
>
> AL092011, IRENE, 20110821, 1200,  , TS, 16.8N,  62.2W,  45, 1005,  130,    0,    0,
>   70,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
>
> AL092012, ANOTHER_NAME, 20110821, 1800,  , TS, 17.5N,  63.7W,  50,  999,  130,   20,    0,
>   70,   30,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
>
> AL092012, ANOTHER_NAME, 20110822, 0000,  , TS, 17.9N,  65.0W,  60,  993,  130,   30,   30,
>   90,   30,    0,    0,   30,    0,    0,    0,    0,

Comment: Every header begins with "AL" so it should be easy to identify where to split the data

Comment: Can't you create an example of input that would help us understand your data and include desired output?

Comment: @zipa there is an example of the data in the link

Comment: Example of data in the link contains single table and you haven't provided us with desired output. Please take a look at how to provide [mcve]

Comment: @zipa it's just a chunk of the csv file, basically the data is the same as this but repeated over and over with different headers..

Comment: I understand that, but couldn't you at lease write up an example with couple of rows and columns that reflect your problem and include the desired output with it?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45876998/5811078) for example. It includes both example of data and desired output. That is what I'm referring to. Questions that contain these along with your current effort receive top quality answers.

Comment: @zipa I've added something to illustrate what I want as best as I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is what I came up with. Might not be the fastest method (interested to know what is, please!) but it does the job. I split the csv into a different file for each hurricane. I then loaded these files in again one by one, reformatting the header as additional columns, and concatenating all of the files into a single data-frame. Please let me know if I could have done this in a more efficient way :)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

# split hurricanes into separate files
partNum = 1
outHandle = None
for line in open("data/atlantic_1851_2017_2.csv","r").readlines():
    if line.startswith('AL'):
        if outHandle is not None:
            outHandle.close()
        outHandle = open("data/part%d.csv" % (partNum,), "w")
        partNum += 1
    outHandle.write(line)
outHandle.close()


# read in each file as data-frame
files = glob.glob('data/part*.csv')
frames = []
for csv in files:  
    with open(csv) as f:
        first_line = f.readline() 
    first_line = first_line.split(',')    
    df = pd.read_csv(csv, skiprows=[0], header=None)
    df['ID'] = first_line[0]
    df['Name'] = first_line[1]
    frames.append(df)


# concatenate into a single data-frame
df = pd.concat(frames)
df = df.drop(columns=[8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])
df.columns = ['Date','Time','Record_ID','Strength','Lat','Long','Max_Wind_Knots','Max_Pressure_mb','ID','Name']
print(df.head(5))
```